# How do i replace two-or-more occurences of the same char with another char?

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to come up with a piece of PHP code that replaces multiple adjacent occurences of a char in a string with only one occurence of that char.

Example:

```
my-string--is---dashed
```

should become:

```
my-string-is-dashed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward solution would be to use a regular expression replace.

```
$output = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $input);
```

In reality, to limit the vacuous replaces, you might elect to go with the following:

```
$output = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', $input);
```

Comment: It works too. But this replaces for **1 or more**, not **2 or more** (which is `{2,}` instead of `+`).

Comment: To clarify, netcoder is referring to the first line of my code (before the edit, where I introduced the second line). Nevertheless, the way, as I understand it, `preg_replace` works, there is not a meaningful performance difference between the two, since `preg_replace` instantiates a new String anyway, taking characters from the source string or the replace string as it goes along.

Answer (score 3):

With a regexp :

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', 'my-string--is---dashed')); // string(19) "my-string-is-dashed"
```

If you meant *any* repeating character, it's a bit more complicated :

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/(.)(\\1)+/', '$1', 'tttooosssdihfjkkk')); string(9) "tosdihfjk"
```

Where `\\1` is basically matched character (matched by `(.)`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/-{2,}/', '-', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace("--", "-", $mystring);
```